Puppeteersharp DownloadAsync fails
I have a website, written in C# and running on .NET 4.8.1 with AngularJS (though that part is not super relevant here).
I'm attempting to use Puppeteersharp to create PDF's on the server  and send them back to the client. This is all working locally on through localhost and IIS Express on a Windows 11 PC.
However, when I deploy this on an Azure VM with IIS (64-Bit Windows Server 2019, 8 GB ram) the process fails because the chrome download fails -- and I'm kind of at a loss for what to try...

I've switched from a TEMP folder path to the inetpub directory where all permissions SHOULD be correct.
I can curl download the .zip from the URL below
I can download it directly from chrome

Failed to download Chrome for Win64 from https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/127.0.6533.88/win64/chrome-win64.zip

   at PuppeteerSharp.BrowserFetcher.<DownloadAsync>d__39.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()     
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)     
   at PuppeteerSharp.BrowserFetcher.<DownloadAsync>d__32.MoveNext() 
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()     
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)     
   at PuppeteerSharp.BrowserFetcher.<DownloadAsync>d__28.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()     
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)     
   at App.Application._Core.Chromium.<DownloadChromium>d__13.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()     
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)     
   at App.Controllers.API.DataApiController.<GeneratePdf>d__1.MoveNext()

Chromium is a wrapper class that I've written around Puppeteersharp..
Here's the code:
Data API controller endpoint:
[HttpPost]
[Route("some-route")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GeneratePdf(RequestDto request) 
{
    var chromium = new Chromium();
    await chromium.DownloadChromium();
    Stream stream = await chromium.CreateStreamAsync(request.Html);

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    stream.CopyTo(ms);

    var result = new HttpResponseMessage()
    {
        Content = new ByteArrayContent(ms.ToArray()),
        StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK
    };

    result.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
    result.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment")
    {
        FileName = $"{request.pdfName}.pdf"
    };

    return ResponseMessage(result);    
}

Chromium:
/// <summary>
/// Wrapper around <see cref="PuppeteerSharp"/> for creating HTML to PDF attachments
/// </summary>
public Chromium()
{
    _Logger = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
    var directory = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
    var driveDownloads = Path.Combine(directory, "chromium");

    _InstallDirectory = driveDownloads;

    _Logger.Info($"chromium class install directory: [{_InstallDirectory}]");
}

/// <summary>
/// Download chromium to the provided <see cref="_InstallDirectory"/>
/// </summary>
/// <returns></returns>
public async Task<bool> DownloadChromium()
{
    SetupChromiumDownloadDirectory(_InstallDirectory);

    _BrowserFetcher = new BrowserFetcher(new BrowserFetcherOptions() { Path = _InstallDirectory });
    _Logger.Info($"browser cache download directory: [{_BrowserFetcher.CacheDir}]");

    // THIS IS WHERE THE ERROR HAPPENS
    _InstalledBrowser = await _BrowserFetcher.DownloadAsync();

    return true;
}

/// <summary>
/// Setup a custom download directory for Puppeter chromium. We need to do this because the default 
/// download directory CAN cause an exception because of a path too long exception
/// </summary>
/// <param name="directory"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
private bool SetupChromiumDownloadDirectory(string directory)
{
    _Logger.Debug($"Settting up chromium directory: [{directory}]");

    bool setup = false;
    bool exists = Directory.Exists(directory);

    var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(directory);

    if (!exists)
    {
        _Logger.Debug($"Directory does not exist, creating it.");
        directoryInfo.Create();
    }

    var rule = new FileSystemAccessRule("Everyone", FileSystemRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.None, PropagationFlags.NoPropagateInherit, AccessControlType.Allow);
    var security = directoryInfo.GetAccessControl(AccessControlSections.Access);

    security.ModifyAccessRule(AccessControlModification.Set, rule, out setup);

    _Logger.Debug($"Setting ModifyAccessControl to SET for directory: [{directory}] result: [{setup}]");

    if (!setup)
        return false;

    rule = new FileSystemAccessRule("Everyone", FileSystemRights.FullControl,
                InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit,
                PropagationFlags.InheritOnly,
                AccessControlType.Allow);

    security.ModifyAccessRule(AccessControlModification.Add, rule, out setup);

    _Logger.Debug($"Setting ModifyAccessControl to ADD for directory: [{directory}] result: [{setup}]");

    if (!setup)
        return false;

    directoryInfo.SetAccessControl(security);

    return setup;
}

Logging from Chromium:
2024-09-20 14:30:53.8350 INFO chromium class install directory: [C:\inetpub\wwwroot\chromium]
2024-09-20 14:30:53.8506 DEBUG Settting up chromium directory: [C:\inetpub\wwwroot\chromium]
2024-09-20 14:30:53.8506 DEBUG Setting ModifyAccessControl to SET for directory: [C:\inetpub\wwwroot\chromium] result: [True]
2024-09-20 14:30:53.8506 DEBUG Setting ModifyAccessControl to ADD for directory: [C:\inetpub\wwwroot\chromium] result: [True]
2024-09-20 14:30:53.8506 INFO browser cache download directory: [C:\inetpub\wwwroot\chromium]


I have a similar problem. I have a console application, and executing DownloadAsync just shuts down my application, without even throwing an exception.

@PeterB have you had any luck identifying your issue?
